# Quickly simulating "mean-time until collision"

Tags: performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics

**Edit** high-level summary of problem/solutions in Mathematica community [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2917025?p_p_auth=uv2Np1BD)

---

Suppose I draw (with replacement) $k$ colored balls from bins with probabilities $h_1,\ldots,h_d$ until some color is drawn more than once.

What's the fastest way to get expected value of $k$?

Adapting JimB's code from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4691369/998) is below, wondering if it can be made much faster. Exact solution using AugmentedSymmetricPolynomials is too slow to be practical for this problem size.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
d = 10000;
p = 1.;
h = Table[i^(-p), {i, d}];
h = h/Total[h];

meanTimeToCollision = Compile[{{h2, _Real, 1}},
   Module[{s, x, mean, k, nsim},
    h = h2/Total[h2];
    nsim = 1000;
    x = RandomChoice[h -> Range[Length[h]], {Floor[nsim], d + 1}];
    mean = 0.;
    Do[k = 2;
     While[
      Select[x[[i, 1 ;; k - 1]], # == x[[i, k]] &] == {} && 
       k < (d + 1), k = k + 1];
     mean = mean + k,
     {i, nsim}
     ];
    mean = mean/nsim
    ]
   ];
meanTimeToCollision[h] // Timing
```

This code lets me estimate these times for various distributions up to $d=1000$ reasonably fast, although I'm wishing for a 10x faster procedure to plot it for $d=10000$ where asymptotics are more obvious

[image]

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mean-time-to-collision.nb)

Comment: Naive question: Is this problem in some way different from your recent weighted birthday question? (I have no objection if they’re the same, just checking whether my sanity left town for the weekend.)

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: Hi Danny, Doesn’t  the birthday problem have (approximately) uniform probabilities of  \sigmeq 1/365?

Comment: Hey Craig, yes it does. I should add a link to the prior question, which posited nonuniform probabilities. Except I’m doing this on a phone, and adding links is…real work (not for young people, of course).

Comment: OK, here’s [that link (maybe, if this works…)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284677/51).

Comment: Oh... I didn't read "your recent weighted birthday question".  Silly me.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau two problems are [different](https://mathoverflow.net/a/446167/7655). Their asymptotic solutions have identical functional form but different constants, mean time until first collision constant is $2\log 2\approx 1.223$, size of group for 50% chance of shared birthday, the constant is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=1.253...$. But fast algorithm for birthday problem would would be a good proxy if it's easier to optimize. Relevant links summarized in [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-mean-time-to-collision.nb)

Comment: using `Do[k = 1;  While[++k == Length[Union@x[[i, ;; k]]]];
 mean += k, {i, nsim}]` gives  small speed-up.

Comment: To OP: The diagram notation does not make sense: Why do you show a diagram with horizontal axis marked $R$ when $R$ is not defined, and should presumably be $d$ (the number of differently coloured balls).

Comment: It is also not time to collision: there is no time (the number of draws), and there is no collision either (you appear to intend to draw until two colours are the same).

Comment: @wolfies thanks for the comment (I have your book!). $R$ is the "effective number of bins", and is equal to $d$ when $p_1=p_2=\ldots=p_d$, the underlying motivation is is given [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446149/birthday-problem-for-non-uniform-probabilities) for a related problem. I used term "collision" because of [similarity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348365/expected-number-of-drawings-to-find-collision/) of this problem to "hash collision" problem

Comment: I'm curious if the form of the probabilities you use in your example (`h = Table[i^(-p), {i, d}]; h = h/Total[h];`) is your targeted interest or is it necessary to have a general solution?  A general solution would be great but is it necessary for your objective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**  Added an estimate of the standard error of the sample mean because an estimate without a measure of precision is at best of unknown value.

Because a "collision" will typically happen long before $d=10,000$, initially obtaining a sample of smaller size than 10,000 followed by a supplementary sample if necessary can considerably reduce the computation time.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
d = 10000;
p = 1.;
h = Table[i^(-p), {i, d}];
h = h/Total[h];
meanTimeToCollision = Compile[{{h2, _Real, 1}}, 
   Module[{s, x, mean, k, nsim, threshold, y, se, k2}, 
    h = h2/Total[h2];
    threshold = 50;
    nsim = 1000;
    x = RandomChoice[h -> Range[Length[h]], {Floor[nsim], Min[threshold, d + 1]}];
    mean = 0.;
    k2 = 0;
    Do[k = 2;
     While[
      Select[x[[i, 1 ;; k - 1]], # == x[[i, k]] &] == {} && 
       k < threshold, k = k + 1];
     If[k == threshold && Select[x[[i, 1 ;; k - 1]], # == x[[i, k]] &] == {}, 
      y = RandomChoice[h -> Range[Length[h]], Floor[d + 1 - threshold]];
      x[[i]] = Join[x[[i]], y];
      While[Select[x[[i, 1 ;; k - 1]], # == x[[i, k]] &] == {} && 
        k < (d + 1), k = k + 1]];
     mean = mean + k;
     k2 = k2 + k^2, {i, nsim}];
    mean = mean/nsim;
    se = Sqrt[(k2 - nsim*mean^2)/(nsim (nsim - 1))];
    {mean, se}]];
meanTimeToCollision[h] // Timing
(* {0.015625, {11.857, 0.201656}} *)
```

I've arbitrarily chosen 50 as the initial sample size threshold.  Something else might be better.  And maybe sequential thresholds might make it more efficient.

Comment: can you reality check my mn function. Essentially it just draws from distribution till encounters something already drawn and calculates length of draws. Any way +1

Comment: @ubpdqn Gladly.  But first I need to figure out `NestWhile` as I've not used that function before.  I'll also check it against the exact values.

Comment: Thanks. NeetWhile is  continued f(f(…f(x)) while condition met. Stop when not met. Outputs ‘nesting’ were condition not met. A better condition than my messy Tally is: Length[#]==Length[Union@#]&. This iterates while no duplicates in output…@kglr neat trick

Comment: Thanks for the tips, this was the fasted method for $d<100$ (also using MKL as random number generator), kglr's solution was faster for d>1000, community [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2917025?p_p_auth=uv2Np1BD)

Comment: Because @kglr gave the faster approach for your objective of large $n$, that answer should be the one accepted.

Comment: @ubpdqn Sorry, I haven't forgotten.  Just too many other things going on right now.

Comment: @JimB it’s fine. It is very low priority. This question stimulated a lot of discussion and I can’t say I understand at all the higher order aum but it has been interesting to observe.

Answer (score 4):

```
SeedRandom[Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
d = 10000;
p = 1.;
h = Table[i^(-p), {i, d}];
h = h/Total[h];
```

Note that, with `nsim = d = 10000`, generating the random 10000$\times$10000 matrix already takes more than half of the total processing time in OP's `meanTimeToCollision`.

```
SeedRandom[1];
RandomChoice[h -> Range[10000], {10000, 1 + 10000}]; // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 6.41687
> ```

In the following, `singledraw` generates and processes a single sample `RandomChoice[h -> Range[10000], 1+10000]`. We use `singledraw` with [`ParallelTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParallelTable.html) to get the desired speed-up:

```
ClearAll[singledraw]
singledraw = Module[{rc = RandomChoice[# -> Range[Length[#]], Length[#] + 1], 
     ctime = 0., k = 1}, 
  While[++k == Length[Union@rc[[;; k]]]]; ctime += k] &;

SeedRandom[1];
singledraw[h] // Timing
{0.004907, 9.}

SeedRandom[1];
sample = ParallelTable[singledraw[h], 10000, ProgressReporting -> False]; //
   Timing // First
```

> ```
>  0.740078
> ```

```
Mean @ sample
```

> ```
>  12.1707
> ```

```
dist = FindDistribution[sample - 2]
MixtureDistribution[{0.705792, 0.294208}, 
 {NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 0.296478], 
  NegativeBinomialDistribution[8, 0.327494]}]

Show[Histogram[sample, {1}, "PDF"], 
 Plot[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[sample, 
    "Oversmooth", {"Bounded", {2, \[Infinity]}, "Gaussian"}], x], 
   {x, 2, 50}], 
 DiscretePlot[PDF[dist, x - 2], {x, 2, 50}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]]], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Comment: clever use of Union to detect prior colour drawn. +1 Much better than my  use of Tally.

Comment: I find similarity of results reassuring: see [here](https://i.imgur.com/hfix2Tu.jpg)

Comment: @ubpdqn, i think we are using the same idea with different implementations.

Comment: yes…I learn so much from your elegant code. Just wanted a reality check :)

Comment: thank you for the kind words @ubpdqn. Actually, I have learned much more from your clean/clear/detailed posts.

Comment: this is the fastest solution for $d=10000$, about 3x faster on my laptop. For $d=100$ the other solution is faster. Summarized in community [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2917025?p_p_auth=uv2Np1BD)

Comment: +1 I do have a minor suggestion about the figure.  As the positive probabilities start at 2, the following gives a slightly better match to the data:  `dist = FindDistribution[sample - 2]; Show[Histogram[sample, {1}, "PDF"], Plot[PDF[SmoothKernelDistribution[sample, "Oversmooth", {"Bounded", {2, \[Infinity]}, "Gaussian"}], x], {x, 2, 50}], DiscretePlot[PDF[dist, x - 2], {x, 2, 50}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]]], ImageSize -> Large]`.

Comment: Thank you @Jim. I updated with the new figure.

Answer (score 3):

**Updated answer**
Refer to functions in original answer.

```
     pl = ListPlot[
Table[{1/(prob[j].prob[j]), mn[1000,
prob[j]],  {j,
Join[Range [10, 500, 10], Range [1000,
10000, 1000]]}],
PlotRange -> Full]
```

Using R as defined in hyperlink:

```
 Show[pl, ListPlot[Table[{1 / (prob[j].
prob[j]), Sqrt[Pi / (2 prob[j].
prob[j])}, (j, 10, 10000, 10}1,
Joined -› True, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Interpreting question as number of draws till two sequential balls of same colour are drawn:

If my interpretation is still incorrect please let me know.

Setting up

```
prob[n_] := Module[{h = Table[1./i, {i, n}]},
  h = h/Total[h]]
f[x_, p_] := Append[x, RandomChoice[p -> Range[Length[p]]]]
```

Example draws:

```
 example[p_] := 
 NestWhile[f[#, p] &, Nest[f[#, p] &, {}, 2], #[[-1]] != #[[-2]] &]
```

For example: `example[prob[10000]]` yields:
{235, 3, 67, 8, 204, 2486, 1785, 1668, 2406, 89, 6, 309, 60, 120, 1, 
386, 1, 2, 92, 1, 21, 4329, 257, 19, 2, 26, 3, 4326, 1317, 540, 2648, 
14, 2224, 2, 1, 1}

Simulating:

```
sim[n_, p_] := 
 Mean[Table[
    Length[NestWhile[f[#, p] &, 
      Nest[f[#, p] &, {}, 2], #[[-1]] != #[[-2]] &]], n]] // N
```

Sample sizes of 1000:

```
ListPlot[
 Table[{j, sim[1000, prob[j]]}, {j, 
   Join[Range[10, 500, 10], Range[1000, 10000, 1000]]}], 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

Note this does not follow the function in OP except for small values of d.

[image]
**Original answer**

This original answer was number of draws till a ball of same colour than previous draws.

Generalizing probability distribution:

```
prob[n_] := Module[{h = Table[1./i, {i, n}]},
  h = h/Total[h]]
```

Calculating means from simulation  using [`NestWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html)

```
f[x_, p_] := Append[x, RandomChoice[p -> Range[Length[p]]]]
mn[n_, p_] := 
 Mean[Table[
    Length[NestWhile[f[#, p] &, {}, Max[Tally[#][[All, 2]]] <= 1 &]], 
    n]] // N
```

Simulations using 1000 samples:

```
ListPlot[
 Table[{j, mn[1000, prob[j]]}, {j, 
   Join[Range[10, 500, 10], Range[1000, 10000, 1000]]}], 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, didn't mean consecutive, consecutive same color seems like a simpler problem, rephrased the original question for clarity

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov see update. My original answer was the case of number of draws till drawing a colour already drawn. Using your R definition I have updated. You can of course use larger sample sizes.

Comment: hm, [trying](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-ubpdqn-answer.nb) your code for the example in original post gives me something that's off by factor of 4 from true answer

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov use function mn NOT sim. If you read my answer. I first answered question based on number of draws  till previous colour: mn. If you look at code sim it is clearly number of draws till consecutive same colour…which of course will be longer. As you ignored my original answer I assumed I interpreted incorrectly. If you look at ORIGINAL answer, I suggest re-run: mn.

Comment: Running mn[100000,prob[10000]] yields 12.2641. Closer to your ‘true’ answer. Note this a sample size of 100000.

Comment: See [here](https://imgur.com/a/6amb5qw) running sample sizes 10000

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different strategy. I am not sure if it is faster or not, but put it out there to consider.

Create a random sequence with weights:

```
roll[number_, length_] := 
 RandomChoice[1/Range[1, number] -> Range[1, number], length]
```

Look for sequential pairs by rotating a list of a given size:

```
RepeatedTiming[
With[{try = roll[100000, 1000] },
 FirstPosition[Most[Transpose[{try, RotateLeft[try]}]], {a_, a_}]
 ]
]
```

About 0.1 seconds.

If the number of colors is very large then use sequential rolls

```
findFirstPair[number_, trialLength_] := 
 Block[{count = -1, position = Missing["NotFound"]}, 
  While[position == Missing["NotFound"], count++;
   position = 
    With[{try = roll[number, trialLength]}, 
     FirstPosition[
      Most[Transpose[{try, RotateLeft[try]}]], {a_, a_}]]];
  count trialLength + position[[1]]
  ]
```

For example:

```
findFirstPair[1000000, 100]
```

Find a mean of 100 attempts

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 Mean[Table[findFirstPair[1000000, 1000], {100}]]
 ]
```

About 10 seconds.  I didn't try to find the optimal trialLength for a given number of colors.

Answer (score 2):

```
SeedRandom[Method -> "MersenneTwister"];
d = 10000; p = 1.; h = Normalize[Table[i^(-p), {i, d}], Total];
```

We process `RandomChoice[h -> Range[Length[h]]]` output to transform it to a draw from `MultinomialDistribution[1, h]`.

(Somehow, more direct approach using `RandomVariate[MultinomialDistribution[1, h]]` is much slower).

To find the time to first collision  we accumulate draws until the maximum of accumulated draws becomes 2:

```
ClearAll[oneHot, drawMND, ttcMND]

oneHot = ReplaceAll[x_Integer :> UnitVector[Length @ h, x]];

drawMND := oneHot @ RandomChoice[h -> Range[Length[h]]];

ttcMND := Module[{ttc = 0., k = 1, r0 = drawMND}, 
  While[Max[r0 += drawMND] < 2, k++]; ttc += k; ttc]

SeedRandom[1];
ttcMND // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.002681, 8.}
> ```

Use `ttcMND` in `ParallelTable` to generate a sample of size 10000:

```
SeedRandom[1];
sampleMND = ParallelTable[ttcMND, 10000, ProgressReporting -> False]; // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.746258, Null}
> ```

```
Through[{Min, Mean, Median, Max} @ sampleMND]
```

> ```
> {1., 11.2721, 10., 49.}
> ```

```
dst = FindDistribution[sampleMND]
```

> ```
> NegativeBinomialDistribution[3, 0.213528]
> ```

```
Show[Histogram[sampleMND, {1}, "PDF"], 
 SmoothHistogram[sampleMND], 
 DiscretePlot[PDF[dst, x], {x, 0, 50}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Medium]]], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]